# Reflection for nested classes

Tags: scala, reflection, nested-class

I see that most people who have been playing with ScalaSigParser, in an effort to ser/des idiomatic Scala case classes in a nice way, have avoided this issue, but I'd like to know if it's possible.  I have a situation much like the following:

```
trait OuterTrait {
  abstract class InnerAbstract(i: Int)
}

object OuterObject extends OuterTrait {
  case class InnerConcrete(i: Int) extends InnerAbstract(i)
}

val bippy = OuterObject.InnerConcrete(123)

val s = serialize(bippy)

// time passes...

val obj = deserialize[OuterObject.InnerConcrete](s)
```

So, I can find the ScalaSig for OuterTrait, but I haven't managed to find a nice general way to identify the outer object from the InnerConcrete class.  Any protips?

Comment: Hey downvoter, could you let me know why? :)

Comment: What do you start with? An instance of `java.lang.Class` for the `InnerConcrete` class? And you want to find the `Class` for the outer object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is navigating from the `Class` of the inner object to the `Class` of the outer object, the issue may be fixed in Scala trunk, one of the tickets concerned beeing [SI-4983](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4983).